# VB.NET: Creating a transferrable .bin file

Tags: vb.net

I am writing a project that has player accounts, and stores simple information about them in a class called "PlayerAccount." Things like the number of puzzles they have solved,the quickest time they have solved a puzzle in, total time spent solving puzzles, etc. I have a high-scores board which ranks players on these different criteria. Players are stored in an array (the array is in an class called "PlayerLibrary"), which is then saved as a .bin file called PlayerLibrary.bin. I wanted to test this high-score board out properly, but I was having a little trouble artificially creating the data to test out different things about it. So, rather than mess with the rest of my code, I created a little tool in a separate console project to do this. Basically, I copied and pasted the classes "PlayerAccount" and "PlayerLibrary," changed a couple of bits from private to public and added a little error checking relevant to the tool, and then created a small interface to create and edit .bin files, so I could easily add, delete and edit all details about players. This is all finished and works fine. I can save and load files in this separate tool. It all works fine. However, as soon as I try to load a file created by this tool in the main program I get this error:

> Unable to find assembly 'Player Library Tool, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Here are my save and load subs from the main program (Both found in PlayerLibrary):

```
Sub binSave()
        Dim fsWrite As FileStream = New FileStream("PlayerLibrary.bin", FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
        Dim bf As New BinaryFormatter
        bf.Serialize(fsWrite, ArrPlayers)
        fsWrite.Close()
End Sub

Sub binLoad()
    Dim fsRead As New FileStream("PlayerLibrary.bin", FileMode.Open)
    Dim bf As New BinaryFormatter
    ArrPlayers = bf.Deserialize(fsRead)
    fsRead.Close()
End Sub
```

I would be very grateful if anyone could tell me what I need to do to make these files transferable.

Comment: Rather than copy pasting the class files into your console project, you need to reference your main project (or a shared dll) instead. Otherwise the classes are different.  The binary serialization contains class information and your console project's classes, while identical, are not the same. Thus your error.

Comment: I would have made a reference to the main application in the console application rather than copying the code. That way the binary serialization is using the exact same classes.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Okay, thanks. That makes sense. I don't suppose you could point me in the right direction with how to do that?

Comment: Are both the main application, and the tool in the same solution?  If so, just expand the tool's project node in solution explorer, right click on the references, and add a project reference to the main app.  If not, do the same thing, but instead of a project reference, add a file reference by  browsing to the compiled .exe output from the main application.

Comment: An even better, but slightly more involved solution, would be to add the "data" classes as classes in a shared "library" project in the same solution as both the main application and the tool.  You can then reference this data assembly from both of the other proejcts, or any other projects you add the need to same data.  Anything shared between them can go in to this library.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Okay, I have referenced the main project now. They were separate solutions. Do I need to make new classes that inherit from the ones in the main project so I can keep my tweaks so that they work the way I want in console?

Comment: If you do that, you won't be able to load the serialized data again.  Binary Serialization is very strict about the types it works with.  Any deviation will make it impossible to deserialize the data without doing some *very* complex stuff with serialization surrogates.  Could you give us some idea of what kinds of tweaks you need to make to the classes?  we might be able to help you solve it in a different way that will work for everything you need to do.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Because the main project will already have a PlayerLibrary file, it will never have to deal with empty files. However when I first create a file, I need to be able to be able to use files with nothing in yet. I am going to try to fiddle around a bit and see if I can do it all outside the class. I will let you know how it goes. Thanks for the help so far. I wouldn't even considered this on my own.

Comment: You should try to keep the data classes that get serialized as simple as possible.  Shallow classes with simple public properties on them are best for serialization.  You can then "Wrap" these data classes up inside other classes (see favoring composition over inheritance) that add the behaviors you want.  Depending on how deep you go with this pattern, this can get fairly complex.  You will need to find a balance in your code.

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind.  If you ever change the structure of the serialized data by adding a new property, removing an existing one, or changing the property type, your old serialized data will probably fail to load.  You can get around that by implementing `ISerializable` and wiring a "version number".  Then when the class gets deserialized (in the special constructor), you can check what version was and "upgrade" the data as appropriate.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Thanks, I will keep that in mind. It seems to be working without too much issue. One thing though, when I copied the classes, I changed some bits to public just because it was easier and nobody else would see that code. Now that it is my main program it is using I have put in "Set xyz (value)" subs. How do I refresh the reference and get them to come up in the second program.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Ah, Got it. I just needed to build again. One problem I do have is that the main project is only set to work with one filename. Of course the separate tool creates different files, so it uses its own names, and files are renamed when you want to use them with the main project. However, this is causing problems because the Player Libraries from the main program are not saving, because they are only set to save to that one name.